# HIVE STRING TO DATE CASTING

Tags: string, date, casting, hive

I am facing problem in converting string to date type. While importing the data using hive I have got a column activation_date with type string (as I was unable to import it as date type) and I want to convert it into date type.

Example

Activation_date
7-MAR-13
12-APR-12

I want it as 07-03-2013 in hive.

Answer (score 6):

A combination of date functions in hive can be used to get this.

> select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('7-MAR-13', 'd-MMMM-yy')))
>   from table_name

Output:

> 2013-03-07