# hive cast string to date in 'dd/MMM/yyyy' format order by and group by issue

Tags: date, datetime, hadoop, hive

I've date stored as `[27/Feb/2016:00:24:31 +0530]`.
I want date format in `27/Feb/2016` and also want to order by it.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992649/hive-string-to-date-casting) solution but it returns in form `2016-02-27` and also orders properly.

```
SELECT 
TO_DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( SUBSTR( time, 2, 11), 'dd/MMM/yyyy' ))) AS real_date,
url 
FROM cleanned_logs 
ORDER BY real_date ASC;
```

To get desired format i tried with `date_format()` function.It is not available in 1.2.1 so i switched to it from 1.0.1.

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( SUBSTR(time,2,11),'dd/MMM/yyyy')), 'dd/MMM/yyyy') AS real_date,
url 
FROM cleanned_logs 
ORDER BY real_date ASC;
```

It gives me desired format but does not order properly.

UPDATED:

```
SELECT display_date,COUNT(url) FROM 
(
SELECT SUBSTR(time,2,11) as display_date,url,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(time,2,11),'dd/MMM/yyyy') as real_date FROM cleanned_logs order by   real_date ASC 
)b  group by real_date;
```

Creates problem in grouping. Here hive expects `real_date` in select clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up the formatting or display of data, with the underlying data itself.  If the table stores a date as a string formatted in one manner, `[27/Feb/2016:00:24:31 +0530]` it's still a string, and strings sort differently than actual dates, timestamps, or numbers.

Ideally, you would store the date as a `TIMESTAMP` datatype.  When you want to display it, use `DATE_FORMAT`, and when you want to sort it, use `ORDER BY` on the underlying data field.  So if your field is of type `TIMESTAMP` called `some_time`, you could query as

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(some_time, 'dd/MMM/yyyy')
FROM some_table
WHERE some_condition
ORDER BY some_time DESC
```

If you're stuck with a string that's stored as a valid timestamp value, then you'll have to do more work, perhaps

```
SELECT SUBSTR(some_time, 2, 11)
FROM some_table
WHERE some_condition
ORDER BY unix_timestamp(SUBSTR(some_time,2,11), 'dd/MMM/yyyy'))
```

The second option displays the value as desired, and orders by a number -- a unix timestamp is just a number, but it has the same order as the date, so no need to cast that further to an actual date.

Comment: Yeah i got confuse as string return type is written in both the function documentation. I've tried 2nd option earlier but hive expects group by filed in select clause.

Comment: The `group by` is needed when there's an aggregate function in the select -- you added `COUNT` and that's what you would need to group by.

Comment: Yeah but i also need count value for each date.